# two columns view as one column SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two columns one of them for foreign_ID and the second for local_ID in on table, if the foreign_ID have number the local_ID will null value ,and in contrary if the local_ID have number the the foreign_ID have null value,  can I make the two columns as one column?, that mean if the foreign_ID have number it will display the value ,or if th local have the value it will display.

```
foreign_ID |local_ID
---------------------
null       | 1
1          | null
2          | null
```

in view I want to become as

```
user |
-------
  1
  1
  2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`coalesce` will return the first non-null value in the list of columns

```
select coalesce(foreign_ID, local_ID) as `user`
from your_table
```